# Spaces threatened by a king(checkers)

Tags: python

```
queen = [x - 1, y - 1]
spaces = [[],
         [],
         [],
         [],
         [],
         [],
         [],
         []]

for y in range(8):
    for x in range(8):
        # queen check
        if x == queen[0] and y == queen[1]:
            spaces[y].append("D")
            
         # diagonal check
        elif y < queen[1]:
            if queen[0] - x == queen[1] - y:
                spaces[y].append("*")
        
        elif y > queen[1]:
            if x - queen[0] == y - queen[1]:
                spaces[y].append("*")
        
        # straight check
        elif x == queen[0] or y == queen[1]:
            spaces[y].append("*")
        
        else:
            spaces[y].append(".")
```

In this code I go from the upper left corner of a board and check each one of the spaces if they either the queen, in which case I append D, or if they are diagonal from the queen or in the same column or line as the queen in which case I append *. If none of these are filled I append a dot.

When I run the code without the diagonal check I get this correct output:

[image]

But when I run it with the diagonal check I get this mess:

[image]

I don't have any idea why this is happening, could someone help please?

Comment: could you update your question to show the values of `x` and `y` please?

Comment: By “spaces threatened by a king(checkers)”, do you mean “squares threatened by a queen (chess)”? Anyway, think about what happens if `y < queen[1]` but the inner `if` condition isn’t satisfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building on @Cubix48's answer, you can condense the code a bit more like so:

```
queen = [x - 1, y - 1]
spaces = [[],
         [],
         [],
         [],
         [],
         [],
         [],
         []]

for y in range(8):
    for x in range(8):
        if x == queen[0] and y == queen[1]:
            spaces[y].append("D")
            
        if queen[0] - x == queen[1] - y or x - queen[0] == queen[1] - y or x == queen[0] or y == queen[1]:
            spaces[y].append("*")
        
        
        else:
            spaces[y].append(".")
```

Output:

```
[['.', '.', '.', '*', '.', '.', '.', '*'],
 ['*', '.', '.', '*', '.', '.', '*', '.'],
 ['.', '*', '.', '*', '.', '*', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '.', '*', '*', '*', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['*', '*', '*', 'D', '*', '*', '*', '*', '*'],
 ['.', '.', '*', '*', '*', '.', '.', '.'],
 ['.', '*', '.', '*', '.', '*', '.', '.'],
 ['*', '.', '.', '*', '.', '.', '*', '.']]
```

This just takes the straight check and merges it with the diagonal check because they both just append `*` to `spaces`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because you use an `if` condition in another `if` condition.

If `y < queen[1]:` is satisfied but not `queen[0] - x == queen[1] - y`, then `spaces[y].append(".")` will not fire as it should.

---

To avoid this, you can join the two conditions using `and`:

```
elif y < queen[1] and queen[0] - x == queen[1] - y:
    spaces[y].append("*")
```

That way you only add `*` if both conditions are satisfied, otherwise you add `.`.

---

However this code only makes one of the two diagonals, to do both, by combining your two if conditions you can simply replace diagonal check with:

```
# diagonal check
elif queen[0] - x == queen[1] - y or x - queen[0] == queen[1] - y:
    spaces[y].append("*")
```

---

```
* . . * . . * .
. * . * . * . .
. . * * * . . .
* * * D * * * *
. . * * * . . .
. * . * . * . .
* . . * . . * .
. . . * . . . *
```